# Escaping vs. charset_table in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Do I need to include special characters in conf charset_table if I "manually" escape them in my code (python)? I haven't included and it's working fine :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do slightly different things. charset_table, influences how the 'input text' itself is tokenized and indexed as words. (as well as how the query itself is tokenized)

So if you want these 'special chars' to taken as seperators between words, then leave them out of charset table, and escape them in the query[1]. (This seems to be what you have)

But if you want these chars to be taken as word charactors - included as part of words, then they should be included in charset_table and still escaped[1]

[1] (well only needs escaping if they can be mistaken as search query syntax).